# Require Help Structuring Parallel HTTP Requests

Tags: python, django, concurrency, transactions, django-commands

Here's my case. I have three tables `Book`, `Publisher` and `Price`. I have a management command that does loops over each book and for each book, it queries the publisher to get the price which it then stores into the Prices table. It's a very simple HTTP GET or **UDP** request that I make to get the price. Here what the skeleton of my code looks like:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    for book in Book.objects.all():
        for publisher book.publisher_set.objects.all():
            price = check_the_price(publisher.url, book.isbn)
            Price.objects.create(book=book, publisher=publisher, price=price)
```

The code is simple, but it gets really slow and time consuming when I have 10000 books. I could easily speed this up by making parallel HTTP requests. I could make 50 parallel requests this would be done in a jiffy but I don't know how to structure this code.

My site itself is very and small and light-weight site and I'm trying to stay away from RabbitMQ/Celery stuff. I just feel it's a big thing to take on right now.

Any recommendations on how to do this while maintaining transactional integrity?

---

Edit #1: This is used as an analogy for what I'm actually doing. In writing this analogy I forgot to mention that I also need to make a few UDP requests.

Comment: Do you really need transactional integrity for the entire operation? Can't you just update the date of the price and have a transaction per book price?

Comment: What I wanted was that if for some reason if the command crashed or encountered some errors during this long run, then nothing would be saved i.e. all or none. If there's a better way I could get around that issue then I would gladly use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org) package which provides quasi-parallel request processing based on [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/)'s [green threads](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Green_thread). `requests` lets you build a number of request objects which are then executed in "parallel". See [this example](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests).

Green threads do not actually run in parallel, but cooperatively yield execution control. `gevent` can patch the standard library's I/O functions (e.g. the ones used by urllib2) to yield control whenever they would block on I/O otherwise. The `request` package wraps that into a single function call which takes a number of requests and returns a number of response objects. It doesn't get much easier than that.

Comment: How have I missed this library? It sounds great for many of my uses. I'd give you all my upvotes if I could, Simon. Thanks. The problem is that I need to make some UDP requests as well. The book, publishers and price thing was sort of an analogy for what I'm working on and I accidentally omitted the UDP bit. It doesn't look like I can make UDP requests using this module. Thanks and sorry about the omission.

Comment: I haven't used UDP in python, but assuming you have some `socket` based code that does the communication part, you can still use `gevent` to parallelize that.

Comment: Yup, I'm using the sockets module. I've never worked with gevent but I'll read up on it. How does a solution using threads and queues sounds? Like this example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: If you really like the answer, I think you can award it some bounty (i.e. of your own rep). You might have to wait two days though, I'm not sure how it really works.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla The advantage of green threads over POSIX threads or forking on I/O-heavy code is that you get "parallelism" without any of the headaches involved - no locking, no synchronizing, no marshalling of data between processes. It is, however, only one real thread executing your code, which cleverly swaps call stacks in and out when you're waiting for I/O. So if you were to run some compute-intensive task without any I/O, you wouldn't see any performance gains.

Comment: AFAIK, threading is frowned upon in Python because of the global interpreter lock (GIL) which prevents a lot of real parallelism. Multiprocessing however is fine.